# Android - adding data to an excel file

Tags: android, excel, jxl

Good day mates! I want to make an android application that is used to record the attendance of a certain group of people, a class for example. I am searching the internet about my problem and yet I didn't found an answer. My problem is this, I want to have an app that generates an excel spreadsheet and then add data to it from time to time. I have already made an application that makes an excel file but I can't edit or update data in its cells. I respectfully ask for your help with this mates. Any guidance and information will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: please share some of your work, what's working, what's not (share code), have you debugged it? do you have any error logs? any logs at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SQLite Database which is very easy to create and maintain. You need only to create one helper class to perform all db actions.
See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and related examples.